# Disable caching for specific page

Tags: publishing-page, caching, object-cache

I've set up a caching on a SharePoint site. But have one specific page that should never be cached.

How do I disable caching for a specific publishing page on a SharePoint site?
Or how do I flush the page cache programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways:

```
// Stop Caching in IE
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
// Stop Caching in Firefox
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

or you could use the @Output property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606(VS.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy(v=vs.80).aspx

Here you can find all the instruction: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323290

Answer (score 2):

Create a WebPart which calls [`PublishingHttpModule.DontEnableCachingForRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishinghttpmodule.dontenablecachingforrequest.aspx) and insert that on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer is already posted I want to say that in my case the problem was with Content Query Web Part caching. And to disable it I set UseCache attribute to False using SPD.

Comment: Thanks @Serhiy I'm experiencing the same issue in CQWP, and this is a big help!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Web Parts do not inherit from the Page class. So, you may have to use: `Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);`